# Bad font smoothing on dark background in Firefox mac (CSS)

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have designed a website and it has dark background. Im using Helvetica Neue, Arial and Quattrocento (From google webfonts) in my pages. Everything is fine in all browsers in Mac and Win (even IE8) But when it comes to Firefox Mac, it just doesn't seem to understand how to render white text on dark background and all of my fonts look bolder and uglier.

Good Fonts (Chrome Mac):  http://p5x.co/1232

Bad Fonts (Firefox Mac): http://p5x.co/1233

I even added this to my body in css:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
text-shadow:rgba(255,255,255,.01) 0 -1px 1px;
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: That's actually normal font smoothing behavior.

Comment: @BoltClock So all websites with a dark background should look ugly in Firefox Mac?

Comment: It's not just Firefox on a Mac. It's the same for Safari and Chrome, except you have that font smoothing + text shadow trick.

Comment: Is there any equivalent to those tricks in Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of the browser's ability to render the typeface. Google webfonts documentation even acknowledges this.

You may want to consider [Typekit](http://typekit.com/) or [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) as an alternative, though it is what it is. Figure people who use a browser like that are used to seeing that quality everywhere so your site likely won't be the bad apple in the barrel.

Comment: I have Helvetica and Arial installed on my Mac. They are mis-rendered too.

Comment: Edit - Yeah you are right. I should just ignore the fact that looks ugly. But its on my nerves:(

Comment: I feel you man :) Gotta pick your battles in the web realm, that's for sure.